# How are function definitions provided by the header file

Tags: c++, c, header-files

I have three files- main.cpp, file1.cpp and headerFile.h.
**file1 is-**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void function1(){
    cout<<"this is function1 from file1"<<endl;

}
```

**headerFile.h is-**

```
#ifndef HEADERFILE_H_
#define HEADERFILE_H_

void function1();

#endif /* HEADERFILE_H_ */
```

**main.cpp file is-**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "headerFile.h"

int main(){

function1();

    cout<<"this is main function from mainFile"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Until this stage function1() is unknown to main.cpp file.
Now people say that as the compiler encounters `#include "headerFile.h"` in main file it simply copies the code of headerFile.h into main file,
 **hence the main file becomes-**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


#ifndef HEADERFILE_H_
#define HEADERFILE_H_

void function1();

#endif /* HEADERFILE_H_ */


int main(){

function1();

    cout<<"this is main function from mainFile"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, here definition of function1() is still unknown to the compiler. How is this definition resolved ? Kindly explain.

Comment: The *declaration* (signature) of the function becomes known, so the code can be *compiled*. Once each `.cpp` file has been compiled, they get *linked* together into the final progam. This is when all the function *definitions* are matched up.

Comment: Please give some more explanation

Comment: I emphasised the key terms to aid your research. I don't have time at this second to write up a full answer.

Comment: Ohh. No problem you can provide the complete details some time later :)

Comment: @enhzflep asking me the same question "What did your last slave die of?" :p :p

Comment: @Brut3Forc3 - I wasn't trying to be unkind or offensive, as it seems someone has deemed me to be. It was an ill-considered response that aimed to address the manner in which you requested further info from BobTFish - I.e, you gave him permission to furnish a longer answer, rather than asking for more detail. Swapping "you" and "can" in addition to adding a question mark (?) at the end makes all the difference. I imagine you're far more accomplished than I at human languages, I only know one and a _tiny_ part of German. Again, sorry for my poor judgement. :)

Comment: @enhzflep Oops I really didn't meant to be that harsh :( (I really didn't) . I actually said this way because BobTFish said that he didn't had much time and so had I asked him one more question(""Swapping "you" and "can" in addition to adding a question mark (?) at the end "") he might have got offended. That's why I said it this way. Had I the chance now, I would have surely edited my comment :D. No hard feeling man. And thanks, I'll surely take care next time.

Comment: @Brut3Forc3 - No problem, I didn't (ever) think that to be your intended meaning, hence what was supposed to be a joke, along with my explanation and finally, mention of languages. All the best. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function definition is still unknown to compiler at the time of compilation of `main.cpp` (where it becomes `main.obj` or simillar depending on the compiler/platform). It just has to know the signature of that function (its name, return value, parameters), provided by declaration in `headerFile.h`. In the compiled object file there will be written (by machine language).

> here, the user is calling some function1, please, linker, find its address and insert it there.

Now, when you compile `file1.cpp` into `file1.obj`, `file1.obj` will contain compiled `function1`.

Finally, when you link these two files into executable (or library), linker will resolve all issues of calling only declared (but not defined) functions. So the quoted part will become

> here, the user is calling the function1, and it's definition is located at 0x0123ABC.

If you do, however, provide object files with function calls, which can't be resolved, you'll get a linker error (something like)

> /tmp/ccwckoGI.o: In function `main`:
>   /home/user/file.cpp:5: undefined reference to `foo()`

Comment: isn't this a very time taking process.. first compile all files then find all functions that are not defined in main.cpp file and then find definitions to those functions in all files compiled(it would take really long time if number of files are large ~100).

Comment: @Brut3Forc3 Now, it's not - it's *precisely* what is happening during *every* linking of a program/library. *This is simply how linking works.* Although, of course, linking large binaries can take tens of seconds. But then again, compiling them usually takes tens of minutes.

Comment: It takes quite some time (I have not done any measurement), but still, it should be faster that lexical analysis of each source file.

Comment: Sorry I'm still unable to understand how linking function definition and function declaration works. A simple explanation on the above would be appreciated :)

Comment: Basically if I'm not wrong the linker searches every file in that project to match the function definition and once it finds it, it links function declaration to definition, and starts searching for another function definition until all declarations are resolved.

Comment: @Brut3Forc3 "How does C linker work" is quite [googlable](http://www.lurklurk.org/linkers/linkers.html).

Answer (score 1):

The header file - `headerFile.h` contains the declaration of the function, and must be accompanied by a source file - `headerFile.cpp`.

Now, when you do a `#include "headerFile.h"` the declaration of the function becomes known and so the code can be compiled. At this point - when `main.cpp` is compiled, `main.obj` doesn't have definitions of the function. After each .cpp file has been compiled and `.obj` files are made, they get linked together, by the `linker` to give you the program.

Comment: Basically if I'm not wrong the linker searches every file in that project to match the function definition and once it finds it, it links function declaration to definition, and starts searching for another function definition until all declarations are resolved.

Comment: It links all the object files by replacing the references to undefined symbols with the correct addresses. Each of these symbols can be defined in other object files or in libraries. If they are defined in libraries other than the standard library, you need to tell the linker about them.

Comment: No, it doesn't do that on its own - you usually have to do it through a Makefile or your IDE, but you can also do the linking in your compilation statement.

Comment: I meant that during linking process, the linker searches every file to match the function declaration to the function definition and keeps searching until it finds it. Is this how it works ?

Answer (score 0):

```
// headerFile.h

#ifndef HEADERFILE_H_
#define HEADERFILE_H_

// add extern to tell the compiler that this function definition is in other file, yes it is in file1, complied into file1.obj
extern void function1();

#endif /* HEADERFILE_H_ */
```

The linker will find function1()'s definition in the file1.obj. You should add to your build command of course.